# Search view or dialog with submenus?

Tags: android, search, android-custom-view, searchview

I would like to implement functionality when I click on top search toolbar in application, the few buttons appear below search input field, allowing me to select different multi selection sub-menus which are dynamically populated from API, before I submit search. What is the most common way to implement this. What android components should I use. I've tried using dialog for search view container, but I am not sure how to display sub-menu when clicked.[image]

Comment: https://abhiandroid.com/ui/searchview and you can find official documentation of google android serach component https://developer.android.com/training/search/setup here. you need to write custom tag creating mechanism on top those

Comment: You can use your own recycler view and make it populate with your custom adapters. when the search view is selected set recyclerview visibility to VISIBLE else setVISIBILITY to GONE

Comment: @SayokMajumder how do I open submenu and get back?

Comment: You can create individual recyler view item with another recycler view in it something like a  nested recycler view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing was to make FragmentDialog which pops up when search icon in top action bar is clicked. FragmentDialog has gravity set to top and hides the main content like in picure. Dialog has its own layout with searchView and filters below it. It is programatically setting UI components visibility. There is multi selection list view with fixed height, 200dp, and I populate it with different data, depending which button is clicked. They are stacked on top of each other in relative layout  and I hide them on back button and Submit button clicks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an effective answer but still works.

I don't think search you provide that kind of functionality if that provide so, I don't know back to questions.

so you can do is remove search view and put textview there and user textview.addtextchnagedlisnter in android and populate data in recycler view or List view up to you and you can put layout in top of  recycler view or List view.

And you can customize as you want.

Thanks

Comment: how do I open submenu and get back?

Comment: you can do is when clicking on a submenu fetch submenu data and show to current layout and when clicking back showing your parent layout data. that why told you use layout to show you can do whatever you want.